# React Native: Import modules outside of project directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have built a web app using React and Flux. Now I am trying to build a mobile app for the same in React Native. Since except for the view components everything is going to be almost the same, I have placed the RN app source code inside the main repo and plan to use the modules from the parent repo.

My directory structure is something like this -

```
main_app
 |-- src
     |-- app 
     |    |-- some_module_1.js
     |    |-- some_module_2.js
     +-- rn_app
          |-- app
          |    |-- some_rn_module.js
          |   
          |-- index.ios.js
```

Now in my `some_rn_module.js`, I'm trying to import `some_module_1` -

```
import SomeModule1 from '../../../app/some_module_1';
```

This throws an `Unable to resolve module` exception. Is this a problem with the RN packager?

Comment: @kar Please explain that a little more? :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried symlinks, but they didn't help, the error remains. Any more ideas? @akshay_kashain were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo No. Unfortunately because of business constraints, I had to abandon the idea and move on with a separate code base for the mobile app.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430875/how-to-import-file-from-outside-components-in-react/60505792#60505792) worked! for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `npm link` for this https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link